# Scrolling through license with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that will automatically install a program, but during the installation process the user needs to scroll through a license agreement. Because it is not a prompt, I'm having difficulty finding a way to scroll through the text to get to the other prompts.
I do not have access to **expect** packages on my system.

Currently I have:

```
(bash process here)<<EOD
yes
#need something here to scroll through license
no
yes
EOD
```

Comment: What do you type on the keyboard in order to scroll? Space? Down arrow? F8?

Comment: Check your program installer for command line options, there is usually a `--no-confirm` or `--auto-confirm` type option that can be used to automate the install.